# Retrieving a category name from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database. One named `jokes` and the other named `category`.

`jokes`

```
CREATE TABLE `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

`category`

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

My PHP which displays the jokes in a table

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM jokes ORDER BY joke_id DESC';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '';
    echo '<table class="table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<h3><th>Category Name</th></h3>';
    echo '<h3><th>Action</th></h3>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td >' . $row['joke'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>';
    echo '<a class="btn-big white" href="read.php?id=' . $row['joke_id'] . '">Read</a>';
    echo '&nbsp;';
    echo '<a class="btn-big green" href="update.php?id=' . $row['joke_id'] . '">Update</a>';
    echo '&nbsp;';
    echo '<a class="btn-big red" href="delete.php?id=' . $row['joke_id'] . '">Delete</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
Database::disconnect();
?>
```

My question is how would I get the joke's `category_name` to be displayed in the echo `'<h3><th>Category name</th></h3>';` with PHP? Because at the moment, the table just displays a joke, without the category name of the joke. For example: Celebrity Joke: this is a celebrity joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT j.*, c.name 
        FROM jokes j 
         LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id 
         ORDER BY joke_id DESC';
```

And to echo the category name use: `$row['name']`

Comment: how would i do a specific category, such as just a page on a Celebrity  jokes?

Comment: @DrJan-Itor pass the category id in the where clause `WHere category_id = '2'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your query to include the category name.

```
SELECT j.joke AS joke, j.joke_id AS joke_id, c.name AS category 
FROM jokes j, category c 
WHERE j.category_id = c.category_id
```

After that, you can get the category by calling `$row['category']`

Comment: Hey, you can't just walk away without treating us to a celebrity joke ;-)

Comment: Ok ok here we go. On hearing the news Katie Price is pregnant again Frankie Boyle has sent her a thank you letter and started planning a new tour.

Comment: @andewjones what would be the query to select just one category on my category table?

Comment: You would have to add a second WHERE condition. If you append `AND c.name = <insertCategoryHere>` to the above query, you will get your desired result.